# XPath to access element in complex XML

Tags: xml, xpath, namespaces

I need to get the value of `<a:DisplayValue>` element in the below XML.

I tried different ways using XPath but it appears either I am not using the correct XPath or the XML is not defined correctly.

Specifically, I am getting an error message "Namespace with prefix 'a' has not been declared".

The Xpath I used is `/s:Envelope/s:Body/a:Answers/a:FormAnswerData/a:QuestionName[1]`

When I use the below Xpath I am getting "no match"
/s:Envelope/s:Body/GetRequestResponse/GetRequestResult/a:Answers/a:FormAnswerData/a:QuestionName[1]

Below is the actual XML I am using.

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body>
    <GetRequestResponse xmlns="http://intapp.com/Wilco.Service.Web/">
      <GetRequestResult xmlns:a="http://intapp.com/Wilco.Service.Web/Data/" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <a:Answers>
          <a:FormAnswerData>
            <a:AddressAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:AnswerType>Text</a:AnswerType>
            <a:BooleanAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:DataTableAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:DateAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:DisplayValue>912-345-9876</a:DisplayValue>
            <a:NumericAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:QuestionId>14bfb3cb2e6-4-13a3cd74bcd</a:QuestionId>
            <a:QuestionName>MobilePhone</a:QuestionName>
            <a:RelatedPartiesAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:TextAnswer>912-345-9876</a:TextAnswer>
            <a:TextListAnswer xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" i:nil="true" />
          </a:FormAnswerData>
          <a:FormAnswerData>
            <a:AddressAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:AnswerType>Text</a:AnswerType>
            <a:BooleanAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:DataTableAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:DateAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:DisplayValue>202-346-9089</a:DisplayValue>
            <a:NumericAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:QuestionId>14bfba640f0-a-25c218099f</a:QuestionId>
            <a:QuestionName>HomePhone</a:QuestionName>
            <a:RelatedPartiesAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:TextAnswer>202-346-9089</a:TextAnswer>
            <a:TextListAnswer xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" i:nil="true" />
          </a:FormAnswerData>
          <a:FormAnswerData>
            <a:AddressAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:AnswerType>Text</a:AnswerType>
            <a:BooleanAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:DataTableAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:DateAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:DisplayValue>Mr. T</a:DisplayValue>
            <a:NumericAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:QuestionId>14bfbe22e0c-9-bedeb479e2</a:QuestionId>
            <a:QuestionName>EmerContName</a:QuestionName>
            <a:RelatedPartiesAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:TextAnswer>Mr. T</a:TextAnswer>
            <a:TextListAnswer xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" i:nil="true" />
          </a:FormAnswerData>
          <a:FormAnswerData>
            <a:AddressAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:AnswerType>Text</a:AnswerType>
            <a:BooleanAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:DataTableAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:DateAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:DisplayValue>Uncle</a:DisplayValue>
            <a:NumericAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:QuestionId>14bfccc91eb-7-7a1b63329e</a:QuestionId>
            <a:QuestionName>EmerContRel</a:QuestionName>
            <a:RelatedPartiesAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:TextAnswer>Uncle</a:TextAnswer>
            <a:TextListAnswer xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" i:nil="true" />
          </a:FormAnswerData>
          <a:FormAnswerData>
            <a:AddressAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:AnswerType>Text</a:AnswerType>
            <a:BooleanAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:DataTableAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:DateAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:DisplayValue>321-467-9089</a:DisplayValue>
            <a:NumericAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:QuestionId>14bfccd87c4-a-ac3b7a4685</a:QuestionId>
            <a:QuestionName>EmerContHomePhone</a:QuestionName>
            <a:RelatedPartiesAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:TextAnswer>321-467-9089</a:TextAnswer>
            <a:TextListAnswer xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" i:nil="true" />
          </a:FormAnswerData>
          <a:FormAnswerData>
            <a:AddressAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:AnswerType>Text</a:AnswerType>
            <a:BooleanAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:DataTableAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:DateAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:DisplayValue>123-789-0987</a:DisplayValue>
            <a:NumericAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:QuestionId>14bfcceddeb-14-c8e035c212</a:QuestionId>
            <a:QuestionName>EmerContMobilePhone</a:QuestionName>
            <a:RelatedPartiesAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:TextAnswer>123-789-0987</a:TextAnswer>
            <a:TextListAnswer xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" i:nil="true" />
          </a:FormAnswerData>
          <a:FormAnswerData>
            <a:AddressAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:AnswerType>TextList</a:AnswerType>
            <a:BooleanAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:DataTableAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:DateAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:DisplayValue>Chinese - Spoken Level - Fair, Chinese - Written Level - Poor, Dutch - Written Level - Good</a:DisplayValue>
            <a:NumericAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:QuestionId>14c16083084-a-bc76dff8ee</a:QuestionId>
            <a:QuestionName>LangMDDId</a:QuestionName>
            <a:RelatedPartiesAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:TextAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:TextListAnswer xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
              <b:string>4</b:string>
              <b:string>7</b:string>
              <b:string>27</b:string>
            </a:TextListAnswer>
          </a:FormAnswerData>
          <a:FormAnswerData>
            <a:AddressAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:AnswerType>Text</a:AnswerType>
            <a:BooleanAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:DataTableAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:DateAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:DisplayValue i:nil="true" />
            <a:NumericAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:QuestionId>14c1b10eeda-10-c078be069f</a:QuestionId>
            <a:QuestionName>NewLanguageAbility</a:QuestionName>
            <a:RelatedPartiesAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:TextAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:TextListAnswer xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" i:nil="true" />
          </a:FormAnswerData>
          <a:FormAnswerData>
            <a:AddressAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:AnswerType>Text</a:AnswerType>
            <a:BooleanAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:DataTableAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:DateAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:DisplayValue>1234 Main St</a:DisplayValue>
            <a:NumericAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:QuestionId>14c1dfeb6c7-d-773963938c</a:QuestionId>
            <a:QuestionName>StreetAddress</a:QuestionName>
            <a:RelatedPartiesAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:TextAnswer>1234 Main St</a:TextAnswer>
            <a:TextListAnswer xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" i:nil="true" />
          </a:FormAnswerData>
          <a:FormAnswerData>
            <a:AddressAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:AnswerType>Text</a:AnswerType>
            <a:BooleanAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:DataTableAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:DateAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:DisplayValue>San Fran</a:DisplayValue>
            <a:NumericAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:QuestionId>14c1e3d9368-12-94b02069f0</a:QuestionId>
            <a:QuestionName>City</a:QuestionName>
            <a:RelatedPartiesAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:TextAnswer>San Fran</a:TextAnswer>
            <a:TextListAnswer xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" i:nil="true" />
          </a:FormAnswerData>
          <a:FormAnswerData>
            <a:AddressAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:AnswerType>Text</a:AnswerType>
            <a:BooleanAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:DataTableAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:DateAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:DisplayValue>CA</a:DisplayValue>
            <a:NumericAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:QuestionId>14c1e3dfbff-15-98ef4238d0</a:QuestionId>
            <a:QuestionName>State</a:QuestionName>
            <a:RelatedPartiesAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:TextAnswer>CA</a:TextAnswer>
            <a:TextListAnswer xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" i:nil="true" />
          </a:FormAnswerData>
          <a:FormAnswerData>
            <a:AddressAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:AnswerType>Text</a:AnswerType>
            <a:BooleanAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:DataTableAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:DateAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:DisplayValue>98567</a:DisplayValue>
            <a:NumericAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:QuestionId>14c1e3e46b8-18-a8cc17d184</a:QuestionId>
            <a:QuestionName>ZipCode</a:QuestionName>
            <a:RelatedPartiesAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:TextAnswer>98567</a:TextAnswer>
            <a:TextListAnswer xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" i:nil="true" />
          </a:FormAnswerData>
          <a:FormAnswerData>
            <a:AddressAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:AnswerType>Text</a:AnswerType>
            <a:BooleanAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:DataTableAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:DateAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:DisplayValue>admin@hotmail.com</a:DisplayValue>
            <a:NumericAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:QuestionId>14c1e3ed5de-1d-9620413541</a:QuestionId>
            <a:QuestionName>PersonalEmail</a:QuestionName>
            <a:RelatedPartiesAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:TextAnswer>admin@hotmail.com</a:TextAnswer>
            <a:TextListAnswer xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" i:nil="true" />
          </a:FormAnswerData>
          <a:FormAnswerData>
            <a:AddressAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:AnswerType>Boolean</a:AnswerType>
            <a:BooleanAnswer>true</a:BooleanAnswer>
            <a:DataTableAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:DateAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:DisplayValue>Yes</a:DisplayValue>
            <a:NumericAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:QuestionId>14c41d58550-24-13c37f2f719</a:QuestionId>
            <a:QuestionName>Notary</a:QuestionName>
            <a:RelatedPartiesAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:TextAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:TextListAnswer xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" i:nil="true" />
          </a:FormAnswerData>
          <a:FormAnswerData>
            <a:AddressAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:AnswerType>Boolean</a:AnswerType>
            <a:BooleanAnswer>true</a:BooleanAnswer>
            <a:DataTableAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:DateAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:DisplayValue>Yes</a:DisplayValue>
            <a:NumericAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:QuestionId>14c41d51ae7-21-41cf999dcd</a:QuestionId>
            <a:QuestionName>Government</a:QuestionName>
            <a:RelatedPartiesAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:TextAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:TextListAnswer xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" i:nil="true" />
          </a:FormAnswerData>
          <a:FormAnswerData>
            <a:AddressAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:AnswerType>Text</a:AnswerType>
            <a:BooleanAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:DataTableAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:DateAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:DisplayValue>111-222-3333</a:DisplayValue>
            <a:NumericAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:QuestionId>14c1e3f5172-20-812001dba7</a:QuestionId>
            <a:QuestionName>HomeFax</a:QuestionName>
            <a:RelatedPartiesAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:TextAnswer>111-222-3333</a:TextAnswer>
            <a:TextListAnswer xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" i:nil="true" />
          </a:FormAnswerData>
          <a:FormAnswerData>
            <a:AddressAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:AnswerType>Text</a:AnswerType>
            <a:BooleanAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:DataTableAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:DateAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:DisplayValue>222-333-4444</a:DisplayValue>
            <a:NumericAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:QuestionId>14c1e3fa12b-23-122dcff1fcd</a:QuestionId>
            <a:QuestionName>CountryHomePhoneNumber</a:QuestionName>
            <a:RelatedPartiesAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:TextAnswer>222-333-4444</a:TextAnswer>
            <a:TextListAnswer xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" i:nil="true" />
          </a:FormAnswerData>
          <a:FormAnswerData>
            <a:AddressAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:AnswerType>Text</a:AnswerType>
            <a:BooleanAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:DataTableAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:DateAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:DisplayValue>333-444-5555</a:DisplayValue>
            <a:NumericAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:QuestionId>14c1e403301-26-460093938e</a:QuestionId>
            <a:QuestionName>CountryHomeFaxNumber</a:QuestionName>
            <a:RelatedPartiesAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:TextAnswer>333-444-5555</a:TextAnswer>
            <a:TextListAnswer xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" i:nil="true" />
          </a:FormAnswerData>
          <a:FormAnswerData>
            <a:AddressAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:AnswerType>Text</a:AnswerType>
            <a:BooleanAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:DataTableAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:DateAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:DisplayValue>January 1, 2000</a:DisplayValue>
            <a:NumericAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:QuestionId>14c41d173f0-15-3d3a0c5447</a:QuestionId>
            <a:QuestionName>DateOfAdmission</a:QuestionName>
            <a:RelatedPartiesAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:TextAnswer>January 1, 2000</a:TextAnswer>
            <a:TextListAnswer xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" i:nil="true" />
          </a:FormAnswerData>
          <a:FormAnswerData>
            <a:AddressAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:AnswerType>Text</a:AnswerType>
            <a:BooleanAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:DataTableAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:DateAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:DisplayValue>NY, CA, NJ</a:DisplayValue>
            <a:NumericAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:QuestionId>14c41d212de-18-bbf50ffa7e</a:QuestionId>
            <a:QuestionName>BarAdmissions</a:QuestionName>
            <a:RelatedPartiesAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:TextAnswer>NY, CA, NJ</a:TextAnswer>
            <a:TextListAnswer xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" i:nil="true" />
          </a:FormAnswerData>
          <a:FormAnswerData>
            <a:AddressAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:AnswerType>Text</a:AnswerType>
            <a:BooleanAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:DataTableAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:DateAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:DisplayValue>CA, MO, NV</a:DisplayValue>
            <a:NumericAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:QuestionId>14c41d36d52-1b-48abe7ae3c</a:QuestionId>
            <a:QuestionName>CourtAdmissions</a:QuestionName>
            <a:RelatedPartiesAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:TextAnswer>CA, MO, NV</a:TextAnswer>
            <a:TextListAnswer xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" i:nil="true" />
          </a:FormAnswerData>
          <a:FormAnswerData>
            <a:AddressAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:AnswerType>Text</a:AnswerType>
            <a:BooleanAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:DataTableAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:DateAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:DisplayValue>cmt1, cmt2</a:DisplayValue>
            <a:NumericAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:QuestionId>14c41d3d8c3-1e-e13c570278</a:QuestionId>
            <a:QuestionName>Committees</a:QuestionName>
            <a:RelatedPartiesAnswer i:nil="true" />
            <a:TextAnswer>cmt1, cmt2</a:TextAnswer>
            <a:TextListAnswer xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" i:nil="true" />
          </a:FormAnswerData>
        </a:Answers>
        <a:ClientId i:nil="true" />
        <a:CreatedBy>Admin</a:CreatedBy>
        <a:CurrentState>Save Employee Info</a:CurrentState>
        <a:CustomFields xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/IntApp.Wilco.Service.Contracts.Data.Common.Entities" />
        <a:Department i:nil="true" />
        <a:Id>177</a:Id>
        <a:MatterId i:nil="true" />
        <a:Name>Request #177</a:Name>
        <a:Office i:nil="true" />
        <a:PracticeArea i:nil="true" />
        <a:RequestType>Update My Employee Info</a:RequestType>
        <a:RequestedBy i:nil="true" />
        <a:Status>InProgress</a:Status>
      </GetRequestResult>
    </GetRequestResponse>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: Show the code where you use your XPath expession. Also, the error message is pretty darn clear (and your problem is *extremely* common). Have you tried searching for a solution before posting your question?

Comment: I don't have code.  I am using an online Xpath tester at http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html

Answer (score 0):

There are probably *two* problems:

- the error `Namespace with prefix 'a' has not been declared` means that the namespace `xmlns:a="http://intapp.com/Wilco.Service.Web/Data/"` is missing in the context of your XPath (be it an XSLT or something else)
- the XPath should be `/s:Envelope/s:Body//a:Answers/a:FormAnswerData/a:QuestionName[1]` or `/s:Envelope/s:Body/GetRequestResponse/GetRequestResult/a:Answers/a:FormAnswerData/a:QuestionName[1]` to account for the `GetRequestResponse` and `GetRequestResult` elements

Comment: I am getting "no match" when I use the Xpath containing GetRequestResponse and GetRequestResult.  /s:Envelope/s:Body/GetRequestResponse/GetRequestResult/a:Answers/a:FormAnswerData/a:QuestionName[1].

Comment: The online tool you are using explicitly says **The XPath tester fully supports XML namespaces, but the declarations MUST be explicit and MUST be on the root XML element.**; if you move there the declaration of the `a` namespace it also warns that **The default (no prefix) Namespace URI for XPath queries is always '' and it cannot be redefined to 'http://intapp.com/Wilco.Service.Web/'**; so, you either use a different tool, or define a prefix for namespace `xmlns="http://intapp.com/Wilco.Service.Web/"`